# how to delete sqlite database table using contextmenu in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, contextmenu

How could I delete the item in listview using ContextMenu? Why when picking the delete in context menu it will force close? Can someone help me?

Here's my code

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("What to do?");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Check Attendance");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Update");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Check Attendance") {
        Intent IntentAttendance = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckAttendance.class);
        startActivity(IntentAttendance);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check Attendance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Update") {
        Intent IntentUpdate = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateStudent.class);  
        startActivity(IntentUpdate);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {   


        db.delete(TABLE_STUDENT, PK_STUDENT_ID, null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: first: `item.getTitle() == "Check Attendance"` of course you should use equals ... even better: you should use menu id ... next: force close == an exception ... prolly because `DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id` is not valid sql ... from this code to deleteing the right rows is a long way ... too long for the SO question

Comment: sir i already get the item.getTitle() == "Delete" the problem is how can i delete the listview item? how do i delete the TABLE_STUDENT from listview?

Comment: sorry i'm beginner in android programming sir

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

To use the `delete()` method of SQLiteDatabase, your second argument should be a SQLite WHERE clause without the "WHERE". You want to delete an item by its primary key, so you need

```
String where = PK_STUDENT_ID + " = " + id; // id of the row to delete
db.delete(TABLE_STUDENT, where, null);
```

If you want to really use best practices, instead you should use a placeholder argument and supply the value separately:

```
String where = PK_STUDENT_ID + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {Long.toString(id)}; // replaces the '?'
db.delete(TABLE_STUDENT, where, whereArgs);
```

Both of the above are equivalent. By the way, I have no idea where the id will come from, hopefully you have access to that in your code.

**Second:**

You really should use a menu XML resource with proper string resources and ids. The only reason code like `if (item.getTitle() == "Delete")` works is because you used the same string constant in the line `menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");`, and since Java interns those string constants, they are literally the same object. It is bad coding practice to rely on this behavior; you should be using `.equals()` to compare string contents, not `==` (or better yet, with proper menu XML resources, you can simply check the id of the menu item).

Comment: sir @karakuri sir where did you you get the id? from {long.tostring(id)}??

String[] whereArgs = new String[] {Long.toString(id)}; // replaces the '?' what? 

sorry sir for being newbie i just want to learn.. thank you

Comment: You are going to need to obtain the id somehow, because you need some way to know which item to delete. I don't know enough about how your code is structured, but I assume your ListView has an `onItemClickListener` or an `onItemLongClickListener`, so you should probably do it there.

Comment: I put a `?` in the where clause. This is a placeholder. When the statement it being prepared, SQLite replaces it with a value. It uses the value I passed in `whereArgs`. I recommend you spend more time reading the documentation for this method and reading tutorials online.